# Как переходить по ссылке

Tags: php

```
public function getUrl($link)
{
    $auth = "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $ch = curl_init($link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', $auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $link);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $res_arr = (json_decode($result, true));
    return ($res_arr);
}


public function parse($link)
{
    $next_page = $this->getUrl($link);
    $next = $next_page['next_page'];
    $url_page[] = "https://ows.goszakup.gov.kz" . $next;
    $this->getProduct($url_page);
}

public function getProduct($url_page)
{
    $url = $this->getUrl($url_page);
    $next_page = $url['next_page'];
    $items = $url['items'];
    foreach ($items as $item){
        $lot = $item['lot_number'];
        $count = $item['count'];
        $amount = $item['amount'];
        $name_ru = $item['name_ru'];
        $url_tender = $item['trd_buy_id'];
        $name_kz = $item['name_kz'];
        $ref_trade_methods_id = $item['ref_trade_methods_id'];

        $tender = [
            'lot_number'                =>  $lot,
            'count'                     =>  $count,
            'amount'                    =>  $amount,
            'trd_buy_id'                =>  'https://goszakup.gov.kz/ru/announce/index/' . $url_tender . '?tab=lots',
            'name_ru'                   =>  $name_ru,
            'name_kz'                   =>  $name_kz,
            'ref_trade_methods_id'      =>  $ref_trade_methods_id
        ];
        $this->addProducts($tender);
    }
}
============== данные ================
{
"total": 12250181,
"limit": 50,
"next_page": "/v3/lots?page=next&search_after=16050982",
"items": [
    {
        "id": 16051262,
        "lot_number": "44957965-ОИ2",
        "ref_lot_status_id": 210,
        "last_update_date": "2021-07-13 14:15:15",
        "union_lots": 0,
        "count": 960,
        "amount": 48000,
        "name_ru": "Шарик",
        "name_kz": "Кішкентай шар",
        "description_ru": "для настольного тенниса",
        "description_kz": "үстел теннисіне арналған",
        "ref_trade_methods_id": 3,
        "ref_buy_trade_methods_id": 6,
        "customer_id": 25507,
        "customer_bin": "150440021889",
        "customer_name_ru": "Государственное учреждение \"Отдел образования Жанааркинского района\" управления образования Карагандинской области",
        "customer_name_kz": "Қарағанды облысы білім басқармасының \"Жаңаарқа ауданының білім бөлімі\" мемлекеттік мекемесі",
        "trd_buy_number_anno": "6074497-1",
        "trd_buy_id": 6074497,
        "dumping": 0,
        "psd_sign": 0,
        "consulting_services": 0,
        "point_list": [
            44957965
        ],
        "enstru_list": [
            0
        ],
        "pln_point_kato_list": [
            "354430100"
        ],
        "singl_org_sign": 0,
        "is_light_industry": 0,
        "is_construction_work": 0,
        "disable_person_id": 0,
        "index_date": "2021-07-13 14:20:01",
        "system_id": 3
    },
```

}
вот json файл.
Как переходить с одной ссылки на другую подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: по каким ссылкам?

Comment: "next_page": "/v3/lots?page=next&search_after=16050982", взять эту ссылку пройти на след и там спарсить продукт после так далее

Comment: добавьте проверку
`if($next_page){
getProduct($next_page);
}`

Comment: не совсем понял куда надо добавить условие

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");` + `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $link);` -  на лицо полное отствутвие понимания. создаем переменную хранящую кол-во добавленных товаров и грузим страницы до тех пор пока её значение не станет равно `total`

Comment: это весь код или есть еще что-то?

Comment: public function handle()
    {
        $link = "https://ows.goszakup.gov.kz/v3/lots";
        $getLink = new Goszakup();
        $getLink->getUrl($link);
        $getLink->getProduct();
        $getLink->parse($link);
    } для запуска кода чтобы спарсить данные